# Adding file paths to Python code

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am currently running the code for a program called [HotNet](https://github.com/raphael-group/hotnet).

In its *simpleRun.py* file, there is a place to insert a file path to be run.

```
parser.add_argument('-mf', '--infmat_file', required=True,
                    help='Path to .mat file containing influence matrix')
```

My path file is `/home/lai/Downloads/influence_matrix_files/hprd_inf_.mat`; and I have tried to add it in as such:

```
parser.add_argument('-mf', '--infmat_file', required=True,
                    help= /home/lai/Downloads/influence_matrix_file/hprd_inf_.mat)
```

But I get `SyntaxError` when running the code:

```
File "simpleRun.py", line 29
    help= ~/home/lai/Downloads/influence_matrix_files/hprd_inf_.mat)
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have also tried to place the path in quotes (as strings `' '`) but that isn't processed.

I have tried removing the `/` however that just returns the following error:

```
NameError: global name 'home' is not defined
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: You should access home expansion through os.environ and concatenate the strings.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of editing the py file, you would simply call the *simpleRun.py* with the argument:

```
python simpleRun.py -mf /home/lai/Downloads/influence_matrix_file/hprd_inf_.mat
```

or

```
python simpleRun.py --infmat_file=/home/lai/Downloads/influence_matrix_file/hprd_inf_.mat
```

Comment: +1 Exactly -- the simpleRun already defines '-mf' . The help argument doesn't *hold* the path, but gives usage help for the mf flag to simpleRun.py .

Answer (score 2):

@cyberbills answer is completely correct, but I wanted to add a little more explanation.

You aren't supposed to edit simpleRun.py to add your path -- it's already defined, and the "help" argument is there to give you help when you actually run the simpleRun.py script from the command line.

To put it another way, the `help` argument doesn't *hold* the path, but gives *usage help* for using the `-mf` flag.

When you use simpleRun.py with "mf", you'll run it as `simpleRun.py -mf <file.mat>`.

(Note: do a `chmod +x` on simpleRun.py if you want to run it by typing `./simpleRun.py` . Otherwise use `python ./simpleRun.py` as cyberbill indicates).

All of the parser arguments in simpleRun.py work this way. The text field in the `help` arg is command line feedback.

You can see it by supplying the `--help` flag to the command:

```
$python simpleRun.py --help
usage: simpleRun.py [-h] [-r RUNNAME] -mf INFMAT_FILE -if INFMAT_INDEX_FILE
                    -hf HEAT_FILE [-ms MIN_HEAT_SCORE] [-ccs MIN_CC_SIZE] -pnp
                    PERMUTED_NETWORKS_PATH [-n NUM_PERMUTATIONS]
                    [-o OUTPUT_DIRECTORY] [--parallel] [--no-parallel]
                    [-ef EDGE_FILE] [-nn NETWORK_NAME]

Helper script for simple runs of generalized HotNet2, including automated
parameter selection.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -r RUNNAME, --runname RUNNAME
                        Name of run / disease.
  -mf INFMAT_FILE, --infmat_file INFMAT_FILE
                        Path to .mat file containing influence matrix
```

Answer (score -1):

`~/` is the same as `/home/lai`, so you want to be using `~/Downloads` or `/home/lai/Downloads`.

Comment: Hi Srijay, thank you for your response. I edited it as you suggested; however, I am still receiving the same error message.

Comment: This is a good catch, however the deeper problem is that the OP is using the argument incorrectly when running the code.